# How to measure the longest width of a square wave?

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm blanking on how I did this in the past.  I'm trying to measure the longest a block of code on a microcontroller will take to execute by toggling a GPIO around that code block.  The firmware works, now I'm just not able to bend the oscilloscope to my will.  The signal is not periodic.  Is this a trigger mode?  I vaguely remember a tracing or history fading option.  I know this may be oscilloscope-dependent, but what that feature is called can help my search in the manual.

The specific scope I'm working with right now is: infiniivision mso-x 4154a

Comment: Trigger source> set threshold, manual or auto sweep> adjust sweep to capture event> choose calc> pw50 or measure pulse width on scope using X ms/div

Comment: Did you enable trace persistence?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, that's it!  `Display -> inifinite persistence`.  Persistence was the word I needed to search the manual.

Comment: If you know (or suspect) which block it is, but not how long, simply alter the microcontroller's program to run it (much) more often...